# Saber si un dato tiene dependencia sin borrarlo posgresql codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

Me gustaría saber si hay manera de saber si un dato tiene dependencia de otro sin borrarlo. explico

si usamos delete from y este dato tiene dependencia no nos permite borrar.

pero yo necesito usar un borrado logico 1-0 y necesito saber si el dato tiene dependencia para borrarlo o no.

hay alguna manera con php de realizarlo?

Comment: Hola, cuando realizas un delete en codeigniter es como si se realizara la consulta en tu gestor, si colocaste la dependencia en `cascade` te va a saltar un error y el dato no se va a eliminar, de otro modo se elimina normal

Comment: Ok entiendo pero en sin. no estoy borrando el dato. lo estoy desabilitando. pero  no quiero desabilitarlo si ese dato da dependencia a otro

Comment: pues en ese caso bastaría con una consulta, pregunta si existen registros asociados a ese dato, si no hay puedes proceder, si necesitas ayuda con código debes editar la preguntar y agregar lo que tienes.

Comment: es que son muchas tablas.. por un ejemplo tengo la tabla roles y la tabla usuario   si borro el rol administrador el cual esta asociado a varios usuarios de manera logica, deberia mandar un error que dicho rol no se puede borrar.

Comment: entiendo, como te dije lo puedes hacer con una consulta, si tienes dificultades para hacerla edita la pregunta y agrega el código que intentaste.